# Excel VBA - Alternative to Loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I've got the following code that loops through and copies certain information based on whether some criteria is met (Column AT = "Y"). There is quite a lot of data to go through so I don't think this loop is the most efficient way of doing this. 
My knowledge of VBA is pretty basic and from what I've read I think there is probably a better way to do this than a loop that searches through +1000 records.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,Niall

```
Sheets("Data JPM Index").Select
Search_Row_1 = 12
Copy_Row_1 = 12
While Len(Range("A" & Search_Row_1).Value) > 0
If Range("AT" & Search_Row_1) = "Y" Then

Range("E" & Search_Row_1 & ":F" & Search_Row_1).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AV" & Copy_Row_1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("A1").Select
Copy_Row_1 = Copy_Row_1 + 1

End If
Search_Row_1 = Search_Row_1 + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Depends what you have in your sheet, you can use **Filter** on column **AT** and then copy the Visible range.

Comment: Column AT is based on a formula so would like to avoid using filters and copying and pasting manually. Or is thee a way of using filters in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Extract_Values1()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim vNewArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim Counter1 As Integer, Counter2 As Integer

startRow = 12
Set wks = Sheets("Data JPM Index")

With wks
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    vArray = .Range("E" & startRow & ":AV" & lastRow).Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(vArray)
        If vArray(i, 42) = "Y" Then
            Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
        End If
    Next i
  'ReDim vNewArray(1 To Counter1, 1 To 2)
   ReDim vNewArray(1 To Counter1, 1 To 5)
    For j = 1 To UBound(vArray)
        If vArray(j, 42) = "Y" Then
            Counter2 = Counter2 + 1
            vNewArray(Counter2, 1) = vArray(j, 1) 'Column E
            vNewArray(Counter2, 2) = vArray(j, 2) 'Column F
            vNewArray(Counter2, 3) = vArray(j, 21)'Column Y Newly Added
            vNewArray(Counter2, 4) = vArray(j, 22) 'Column Z Newly Added
            vNewArray(Counter2, 5) = vArray(j, 34) 'Column AL Newly Added
        End If
    Next

  '.Range("AV" & startRow & ":AW" & startRow + Counter1 - 1) = vNewArray
   .Range("AV" & startRow & ":AZ" & startRow + Counter1 - 1) = vNewArray

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this - that loop works really well. Quick question though - what about if you needed to copy multiple ranges? Following on from above it would be copying the following ranges "E12:F12" (waht the above does), "Y12:Z12" and "AL12" to "AV12".

Comment: I just updated the code. I left the previous code in as comments so that you can see the changes I made.

Comment: RWilson you are a legend - thanks a million for your help with this

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the AutoFilter to copy and paste in a fraction of Loops required.

Consider this data:
[image: initial data]

The code below will paste the cells that the 6th column (`Col 6`) of the range **TestData** with value of **4** to cell **H2**:

```
Sub Q31715032()
    With ThisWorkbook.Names("TestData").RefersToRange
        .AutoFilter 6, "=4" ' Want the 6th column with value 4
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("H2")
        '.AutoFilter ' Uncomment this to remove AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

And the result is:
[image: Results]